# Problems with FPDF and Euro symbol

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, pdf-viewer, euro

I've spent a couple of days sifting through various methods to encourage FPDF to render the Euro symbol, but none have succeeded. I have:

```
$currency = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", '€');
```

Which results in:

> iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an incomplete multibyte character
>   in input string

I've tried a variety of encoding types, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you please check the answers again and reconsider which is actually the correct answer?

Comment: I'm not sure why I marked one as being correct because nothing I tried worked. I've removed the tick from the first answer.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to edit your answer and explain the discussion here, so it's clear to everyone else?

Comment: I removed my, previously accepted, answer for clairty.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You actually **can** generate a PDF with euro signs using FPDF with using euro ascii code: `chr(128)`.

It's good practice to make this a constant. At the top of your script, add:

```
define('EURO',chr(128));
```

Now you can use `EURO` in your script to print the euro symbol.
For example:

```
"Costs: ".EURO.100
```

Will output: `Costs: €100`

Note: This will also work for other symbols with `chr(ascii)`, where `ascii` is the ascii code of the symbol.

Comment: Why not just `"Costs: " . chr(128)`? Also, this should be the accepted answer, not the one promoting a different extension.

Comment: Because `chr(128)` does not make any sense to someone whose reading your code. `EURO` does. You can upvote the answer if you like it to be the accepted answer.

Comment: `chr(128)` makes sense to me... I think my gripe is that your answer starts with instructing us to define it as a constant, where I would see that as 'optional'. You could just as well define it as a variable, or use a function or what not. The key is getting the symbol by using the `chr` function. I think your answer should focus on that.

Comment: This is much better than using an extension.  I need to add the pound sign, (£) which is `chr(163)` if anyone was wondering.

Comment: The trouble I'm having with this answer is that ASCII actually ends at 127. Anything above is a subject to several non-compatible extensions. While this solution will work on most systems with Windows-12xx codepages, it might break somewhere else.

Answer (score 10):

I've searched for ages, and nothing worked - until I used this:
utf8_encode(chr(128))

Comment: Thank you. The additional utf8_encode was also required for me

Answer (score 0):

the `iconv` function worked for me

```
$text = "String with € sign"    
$pdfobj->Write(0,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $text));
```

Answer (score -3):

if You Want to show this line "£4.30" just follow bellow

$text = chr(163);
$pound = $text."4.30 p m";

Note: 163 = pound code;