# Euro in PDF using Ascii

Tags: php, zend-framework

Whenever I make a pdf with the euro sign using alt 0128 ; €, the pdf works fine.
But whenever I define the euro in php with the ascii table using the following code;

```
define('EURO', chr(128));
```

The pdf gets broken and is unable to open.

Comment: I guess you already found [this answer then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443565/2310830) Assuming that is a correct answer, maybe you should show us exactly how you are using that in your real code

Comment: Did you try just `chr(128)`?

Comment: What library are you using to help you create the pdf's